# Инсталляция mxnet(v.0.9.3) для R(Windows)?

Tags: r

В CRAN лежит библиотека mxnet(v 0.7.0). Как инсталлировать v0.9.3 из [Github?](https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/)

Answer (score 2):

Полная процедура описана у меня в [блоге](http://biostat-r.blogspot.com/2017/01/deep-learning-r-mxnet.html).

Цитата непосредственно про установку пакета:

Запускаем из папки `mxnet`:

```
cd R-package
Rscript -e "library(devtools); library(methods); options(repos=c(CRAN='https://cran.rstudio.com')); install_deps(dependencies = TRUE)"
cd ..
make rpkg
R CMD INSTALL mxnet_current_r.tar.gz
```

После чего вносим изменения в `/usr/lib/R/etc/ldpaths` (команда `sudo nano /usr/lib/R/etc/ldpaths`):

```
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/lib64:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
```

Если не нужна поддержка GPU, то сборку библиотеки можно проводить со значениями в файле `make/config.mk` по умолчанию, а также не прописывать никакие пути в `/usr/lib/R/etc/ldpaths`.

UPD Не увидел, что вопрос про Windows (или это было позже добавлено?). Под Windows лучше даже не пробовать - быстрее будет запустить виртуальную машину с Linux и экспериментировать на ней. Для полноценной работы все равно нужен Linux и GPU от Nvidia.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Вопрос был о Win.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Виртуальная машина не устраивает. А почему версия 0.7.0 работает под Вин? Неужели никакой возможности?

Comment: Возможность есть: http://mxnet.io/get_started/windows_setup.html